# Glassware installing Success, but how to activate it on the device?

Tags: installation, google-glass

I was able to successfully instal a glassware application onto my device.  However, I can not locate where to run it from within glass itself.

I have looked in the main menu and tried to see if it was located in "glass launcher".  I could not find it in either of these menus.

How can I access this "installed" glassware?

Comment: Can you post your manifest so I can see how you set up your main activity?

Comment: Is this a third party app U r talking about from https://glass.google.com/glassware/ or your own application that you have developed?

Comment: It is my own application that I have developed, however there it does not always properly install onto Glass such that it has its own card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your own developed application, then in the manifest check if you have added

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
   android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
```

under your launcher activity.

Your res/xml folder will contain a file voice_trigger_start.xml which will contain this

```
<constraints
    network="true" />
```